# c# - How to remove from List using LINQ the elements with X times of repetition?

Tags: c#, linq

I have "myList" of int[].

```
        int[] linha1 = { 1, 2, 2, 2, 3 };
        int[] linha2 = { 1, 2, 2, 3, 4 };
        int[] linha3 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

        List<int[]> myList = new List<int[]>();

        myList.Add(linha1);
        myList.Add(linha2);
        myList.Add(linha3);
```

I want to remove from myList the elements with numbers repeating more than twice. 
Ex.: only "linha1" would be removed because the number "2" repeats 3 times.
Is there a way using LINQ?

Comment: Did you attempt to solve it? What code did you try?

Comment: Try following : var results = myList.Where(x => x.GroupBy(y => y).Max(y => y.Count()) <= 2).ToList();

Comment: I tried this:
myList.RemoveAll(x => x.GroupBy(e => e).Where(e => e.Count() > 2).Any());

But then I realized I was removing all elements.

Thanks! Your Way Worked! @jdwen

Comment: "numbers repeating more than twice" - means that the number appears **four or more** times in a list. For example, in `linha1` the number `2` repeats twice as it appears three times. A number can only **repeat after its first appearance**.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the challenge  try this

```
var linhaTokeep = myList.Where(l =>l.GroupBy(i => i).All(v => v.Count() <= 2));
            foreach (var b in linhaTokeep)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join(',' ,b));

            }
```